# How to correctly unset bits in 64 bit number?

Tags: c++, bit

I want to set all, a part of or no bits of a 64 bit number. However when I print the bit representation, and for example I set only 53 bits, I see, that all bits are 1s. What can be the problem?

```
int main() {

  uint64_t a = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i <= 63; i++)
    std::cout<<((a>>i) & 0x01)<<" ";
  std::cout<<std::endl;
  for (unsigned i = 0; i <= 52; i++)
    a |= (1<<i);
  for (int i = 0; i <= 63; i++)
    std::cout<<((a>>i) & 1)<<" ";
  std::cout<<std::endl;
}
```

EDIT:
I get this output:

> 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
>   0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
>
> 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
>   1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1

But the last one, changed, should not consist of all the ones.

Comment: Please *show* us the output, both the expected and the actual. Edit your question to include it.

Comment: What did you observe when stepping through your code line by line with the debugger?

Comment: `(1<<i)` is an `int` (since that's what 1 is). Sure you are reaching bits beyond 0-31?

Comment: This isn't the problem, but do you really need the extra stuff that `std::endl` does? `'\n'` ends a line.

Answer (score 8):

`1` is a literal of type `int`. If your machine has 32-bit `int`s, `(1<<i)` would invoke undefined behaviour for all `i` larger than 30.

If you want to work with `uint64_t`, do so consistently.

```
a |= (static_cast<uint64_t>(1)<<i);
```

or simply

```
a |= (1ULL<<i);
```

would do the trick.

Comment: In this case, specifically integer overflow of 1 (signed) becoming -1 (also signed, obviously). Once that is promoted to the unsigned 64bit type for the masking operation, that results in all the bits being set to 1 afterwards.

Comment: @user268396 - You should post that as an answer

Answer (score 5):

The behavior of your program is undefined. So whatever result you see is perfectly valid as far as C++ is concerned.

The reason plainly is that `(1<<i)` is an int, on account of the constant 1 being an int. And a shift operation on an int (a signed type) that exceeds the bit limit, is undefined.

So you need to force the expression into being `std::uint64_t`. One such way is this:

```
constexpr std::uint64_t one = 1;

// ...

for (unsigned i = 0; i <= 52; i++)
  a |= (one << i);
```